# Jersey url mapping error

Tags: java, web-applications, jersey, web.xml, jersey-1.0

I have a web application with the following folder structure

```
ProjectName 
     |.. src/main/java
       |.. folder1
         |.. restEndpoint1.java , restendpoint2.java etc
```

with the restendpoint1.java being like

```
@Path("/static1/static2")
public class DoStuff {

@POST
@Path("/static3")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response validation(String inputXML){
```

my web.xml is :

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>folder1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/folder1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Which makes my URL

```
http:\\localhost:port/projectName/foldername/{restendpoint1.path}
```

Is there a way I can eliminate the foldername from the mapping so as I can make my mapping

```
localhost:port/projectName/{restendpoint1.path}
```

How do I manipulate my web.xml to achieve this .

The reason I need to do this is , I need the folder structure to ensure maintainability of the code ( as opposed to grouping everything into one class and making the web.xml map to that class) but I also have to avoid getting the `foldername` in the mapping .

Comment: Well, you could continue to host it at the original URL, and then add a controller method to forward requests to the shortened URL. However, if you want to actually host the endpoints on the shortened URL, you're going to have to tell your server about the endpoints in some way other than using server.xml, since you can't change the context here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put `folder1` in the `url-pattern`. You've already put `folder1` in the packages being scanned for services. By putting `folder1` in the `url-pattern`, you are indicating that you want it to be in the URL. Put whatever you want the URL to be in there. So

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This should make all calls go to your rest services. However, you should probably put some path in there because you don't want to map all of your URLs to REST services (since there will be other URLs that are not REST services). Maybe something like

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```